# how to decrease height of linearlayout which is an image in android

Tags: android, sentry

I want to decrease height of an image which is used as linearlayout in android.How can i do that? My code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/details" 
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primary_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout> 

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/status"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="62dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
   android:layout_weight="0.08" />
```

Decrease the height of imageview doesnot work.how can i do this?

Comment: android:layout_height="100dp" change it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content", may it work

Comment: android:layout_height="fill_parent" change it to    android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: match_parent also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decrease layout_height or decrease it manually from Graphical layout. If even it does not work then you have to check whether that image's layout is overlapping with others or not. If yes then decrease that layout's size.

Answer (score 0):

change height in this tag >> `android:layout_height="100dp"` , use less number for height(80dp) or make it `wrap_content`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```